# How to compare Attribute value with string

Tags: java, selenium

I am using below code to getAttribute of a field on web page :-

```
    List<WebElement> EngDesc = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='EngDesc']"));
        System.out.println("List size: "+EngDesc.size());
        for(WebElement list : EngDesc ){
            System.out.println("search value: "+list.getAttribute("value"));
            if(list.getAttribute("Value").equals("CHARGEABLE")) {
                System.out.println("This is General");   
             }
```

and below is the output I am getting:-

> List size: 1
>   search value: CHARGEABLE
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at newrequestFlow.Index.main(Index.java:81)

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: List<WebElement> EngDesc = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='EngDesc']")).getText();

try this.

Comment: set beak-point check the values..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing says it all as follows :

```
NullPointerException at newrequestFlow.Index.main(Index.java:81)
```

The line `findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='EngDesc']"));` returns only **`1`** entry.
Initially in the `for()` loop you are using **`list.getAttribute("value")`**. But later you are trying to use **`list.getAttribute("Value")`**

> **`value`** and **`Value`** are different attribute and probably there were no attribute present as **`Value`** . Hence **`Null`** is returned and **java.lang.NullPointerException** is observed.

### Solution

```
List<WebElement> EngDesc = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='EngDesc']"));
    System.out.println("List size: "+EngDesc.size());
    for(WebElement list : EngDesc )
    {
        System.out.println("search value: "+list.getAttribute("value"));
        if(list.getAttribute("value").equals("CHARGEABLE")) 
        {
            System.out.println("This is General");   
        }
    }
```

Comment: That proves that I am an real idiot. Thanks it worked now.